# We're sorry, but something went wrong. (Heroku Error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, rubygems

I've just been hit with the " We're sorry, but something went wrong. " error when deploying to Heroku.

Being fairly new to Heroku i'm having trouble identifying the issue, to troubleshoot it.

application.rb

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end

module User101
  class Application < Rails::Application

    #seperate
     # Prevents heroku rake abort on assets compile
    # From http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2012/02/heroku-and-rails-3-2-assetprecompile-error/
    config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false

    # Enable the asset pipeline
    config.assets.enabled = true

    # wysihtml5 css issue - https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/1312
    config.assets.precompile += ['*.css', '*.js']
    #seperate

    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
    # config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)

    # Only load the plugins named here, in the order given (default is alphabetical).
    # :all can be used as a placeholder for all plugins not explicitly named.
    # config.plugins = [ :exception_notification, :ssl_requirement, :all ]

    # Activate observers that should always be running.
    # config.active_record.observers = :cacher, :garbage_collector, :forum_observer

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de

    # Configure the default encoding used in templates for Ruby 1.9.
    config.encoding = "utf-8"

    # Configure sensitive parameters which will be filtered from the log file.
    config.filter_parameters += [:password]

    # Enable escaping HTML in JSON.
    config.active_support.escape_html_entities_in_json = true

    # Use SQL instead of Active Record's schema dumper when creating the database.
    # This is necessary if your schema can't be completely dumped by the schema dumper,
    # like if you have constraints or database-specific column types
    # config.active_record.schema_format = :sql

    # Enforce whitelist mode for mass assignment.
    # This will create an empty whitelist of attributes available for mass-assignment for all models
    # in your app. As such, your models will need to explicitly whitelist or blacklist accessible
    # parameters by using an attr_accessible or attr_protected declaration.
    config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true

    # Enable the asset pipeline
    config.assets.enabled = true

    # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
    config.assets.version = '1.0'


  end
end
```

#### Updated Heroku logs 2:

```
      [StartupBlog]$heroku logs
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/users/sign_in host=startupblog.herokuapp.com fwd="174.95.207.136" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=2ms service=17ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:42:in `call'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:601:in `call'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 
app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/omniauth-1.1.3/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:177:in `call!'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/omniauth-1.1.3/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:157:in `call'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/omniauth-1.1.3/lib/omniauth/builder.rb:48:in `call'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/warden-1.2.1/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/warden-1.2.1/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/warden-1.2.1/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__3394535389802165164__call__3147947447447898363__callbacks'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-03-01T04:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
2013-03-01T04:13:50+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=startupblog.herokuapp.com fwd="174.95.207.136" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=1ms service=12ms status=304 bytes=0
2013-03-01T04:13:50+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/logo2.png host=startupblog.herokuapp.com fwd="174.95.207.136" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=2ms service=9ms status=404 bytes=728
2013-03-01T04:13:50+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
2013-03-01T04:13:50+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-03-01T04:13:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered partials/_footer.html.erb (1.3ms)
2013-03-01T04:13:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block i
n call'
2013-03-01T04:13:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (2.7ms)
2013-03-01T04:13:50+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 3.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2013-03-01T04:13:50+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/assets/logo2.png" for 174.95.207.136 at 2013-03-01 04:13:50 +0000
2013-03-01T04:13:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
2013-03-01T04:13:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
2013-03-01T04:13:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2013-03-01T04:13:50+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 174.95.207.136 at 2013-03-01 04:13:50 +0000
2013-03-01T04:13:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
2013-03-01T04:13:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
2013-03-01T04:13:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
2013-03-01T04:13:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
2013-03-01T04:13:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
2013-03-01T04:13:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
2013-03-01T04:13:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
2013-03-01T04:13:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
2013-03-01T04:13:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2013-03-01T04:13:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
2013-03-01T04:13:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2013-03-01T04:13:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
2013-03-01T04:13:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
2013-03-01T04:13:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
2013-03-01T04:13:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered partials/_header.html.erb (1.0ms)
2013-03-01T04:13:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
2013-03-01T04:13:50+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/logo2.png"):
2013-03-01T04:13:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2013-03-01T04:13:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
2013-03-01T04:13:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
2013-03-01T04:13:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
2013-03-01T04:13:50+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-03-01T04:13:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
2013-03-01T04:13:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
2013-03-01T04:13:50+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there's an issue with your `logo.png` file.  Did you precompile your assets before deploying?

```
rake assets:precompile
```

This will generate the assets for production.  Check in the resulting files (public/assets) and then push back up to Heroku.

Comment: Thanks Richard, unfortunately still being hit with the same error- I've updated the heroku logs in the op after running rake assets:precompile. Hoping something has changed for the better.

Comment: Do you have a `logo` method in your application_helper.rb?  If so, make sure the path is correct... it should be '/assets/logo.png'

Comment: That worked! but oddly it's a really old version? I've ran git push heroku master but it's displaying and older version..I've deleted cookies, and cache, any ideas? Have updated the heroku logs just incase you see anything strange

Comment: Check the version in the /public/assets folder.  `touch` it in your /assets/images folder to force it to update, run precompile again and check it all in. See if that helps.

Comment: Really weird, should i maybe delete all the files in the Public/assets folder and then run precompile? out-with-the-old, in-with-the-new logic?